# beginner, appreciate for any advice!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am hoping that this is the correct forum to post this question. So I recently decided to join Blender but I am overwhelmed with all the information I get. I am an active sketchup and vray user and without any other 3d softwares experience before and my goal for learning Blender is for arch viz and perhaps real time rendering as well now that Blender 2.8 and eevee is out.

I want to get started with the latest Blender 2.8. I tried to watch the blender fundamental tutorials on youtube but the settings,buttons and UI seem different and sometimes its too difficult to follow through.

I know that Blender is completely free and open source so there arent lots of resources from its official organisation to make tutorials regularly. But since 2.8 is out and with lots of changes happened compared to the available tutorials online, is there a specific channel online where I can start learning the right way at the beginner level?

Or if theres any suggestion about what videos can help me get started for using blender 2.8?

I appreciated very much for any advice, I know this type of topics perhaps get posted many time but I am hoping I can get more update responses in relation to the 2.8 release. Thank you so much!

Comment: .. also check out [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/35559)

Answer (score 2):

It can be hard to learn at first but you need to take long and sometimes frustrating baby steps. If possible, try to understand both 2.79b while it is still available for download and also 2.8. 2.8 is still in beta and brand new, as of about a month or 2 ago.

Most tutorials are for Blender 2.7x so I would advise to start off there and use tutorials such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kes2qmijy7w Blender fundamentals. Blender Guru is also a good source for medium to higher level modelling and has just released a video on the new 2.8 layout which I suggest watching Watch both this one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPVpg4_POww, which is the Blender Guru new layout video, and the first link which is a Blender 2.79b video of a similar nature to gather how different the versions are, which is why I suggested to learn 2.79b since there are so many videos available for it. Start small and learn all the functions first. Remember that Blender engine has been removed in favour of the new Eevee rendering engine so as much as possible try to learn in cycles, but couldn't hurt to learn both the blender engine and eevee engine layouts.

Since 2.8 is still new there won't be as many answers and the layout has dramatically changed so it would be hard for a beginner to watch tutorials done in a 2.7x version and follow along in 2.8, which is why I suggest learning 2.79b first. Once you have an understanding of 2.79b then you can transfer allot of skills easily over to 2.8 by finding the new locations of the tools and menus. Good luck with it.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!! relating to your reply, do you mean 2.78 or 2.79? because I saw on the blender website that the prior version of 2.8 beta is the 2.79 version.

Comment: and if you really do mean 2.78, do you mean 2.78a or b or c? because it seems to be multiple versions, tho i am not sure if they r still downloadable

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant 2.79b. I was using 2.78 because of graphics issues my end but yes, 2.79b; the option to download will download the latest version. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I totally agree with @Mark Matthews.  2.79 is still very much like 2.8, and there are quite a few questions on this forum that help newbies to 2.8 find all the buttons and such.  I would strongly suggest starting with Blender Guru's beginner tutorial.  You should be able to find it on Youtube if you search "Blender Guru Beginner"  There are like 7 parts.  Almost all of it is applicable to 2.8, and it's a great start for people new to 3D.  He is also great at keeping you entertained while watching his videos.